# Medium Editor paste options not working

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

This is my config

```
new MediumEditor(".editor", {
    buttons: ['italic', 'bold', 'underline', 'anchor', 'unorderedlist', 'quote'],
    paste: {
        // This example includes the default options for paste, if nothing is passed this is what it used
        forcePlainText: false,
        cleanPastedHtml: true,
        cleanReplacements: [],
        cleanAttrs: ['id', 'style'],
        cleanTags: ['a', 'br']
    }
});
```

When i paste some html text i would expect the `id` and `style` attrs to be removed, aswell as the `a` and `br` tags. But thats not happening, see [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7YjurUuOr2hExUQuNltq?p=preview)

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like you opened an issue against the medium-editor repo here: https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/issues/881 And it looks like this was simply a typo between `cleanPastedHtml` and `cleanPastedHTML` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was a typo between camel casing the option name you passed in: `cleanPastedHtml` vs `cleanPastedHTML`.

If you use `cleanPastedHTML` instead, I believe this will fix your problem.